# Batch delete firestore documents receiving error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run through a loop to batch delete all of a particular event's eventPosts (pictures) however I'm running into the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' to expected argument type 'DocumentReference'`

I know I'm missing something just not sure what it is, here's the loop:

```
db.collection("posts").whereField("eventId", isEqualTo: eventId).getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in

if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    }
    else {
        for document in snapshot!.documents {

            batch.deleteDocument(document)  
        }

        // Commit the batch
        batch.commit() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing batch \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Batch write succeeded.")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
batch.deleteDocument(document)
```

with

```
batch.deleteDocument(document.ref)
```

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) the `deleteDocument()` method should receive the ref to a document as a parameter.